# Writing to a log, inside a timer, that's inside a thread, from another thread

Tags: c#

I'm working on writing an application that scans an imageboard for images, then downloads them. Ofcourse this has to be threaded, because multiple boards could be scraped at once. I've got the basic funcionality done already, but now I'm hitting a wall.

Currently I start threads by giving an url, then press a button, this button starts a thread which points to a class.

My problem resides inside this class, as I'm using a timer there.

Currently the data gets pushed to the log at one go, but should be pushing the data as it is set.

Currently this is my function that is bound to the tick event of my timer:

```
    public void scanForImages(object s, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (status != 1 && status != 4)
        {
            status = 1;
            int i = 0;
            while (status == 1)
            {
                main.updateLog(th.Name + ": Blaat\n");
                i++;
                if (i > 50)
                {
                    status = 4;
                    t.Stop();
                    main.updateThreads("Aborting: " + th.Name, th);

                    th.Abort();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            t.Stop();
        }
    }
```

It is returning output in my textbox, but it's pushing everything at once( All the `th.Name + ": Blaat\n"`

updateLog:
public void updateLog(string txt) 
        {

```
        if (InvokeRequired) 
        { 
            Action action = () => textBox2.AppendText(txt); 
            textBox2.Invoke(action); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            textBox2.AppendText(txt); 
        } 

    }
```

What am I doing wrong? (More code can be supplied, if neccessary)

Comment: Move the `i` variable outside the method and get rid of the while loop.

Comment: Moving it outside of the loop, and getting rid of the while loop only let the message run once. I need it to loop while the status is 1, since the specific imageboard could of deleted the file, returning a 404, so the loop has to quit.

Comment: It "loops" by the Elapsed event firing more than once.  You make it "quit" by disabling the timer.  Be sure to write your code so it is aware how timers work.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm so stupid. If you could post that in an answer, I'll mark it as the answer, because this did it.

Answer (score 0):

you do not give the .updatelog code so we can answer correctly
so...
either you must flush the file inside that function or you must initiate a dispatcher

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                      new Action<string>(main.updateLog),
                      th.Name + ": Blaat\n");
```

Comment: Somehow I don't have the Dispatcher class, googling it gave me the MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher(v=vs.110).aspx but theres no System.Windows.Threading?

Comment: you cannot reference it... just add it at the "using" area---- using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Threading;